# Adding Exterior Physic Engine Library to new Project in Java (JBox2D)

Tags: box2d, jbox2d

I want to import JBox2D libraries into a new project, im new to using exterior libraries so my doubts will seem really stupid but oh well, thats how you learn.

So i kind of followed the tutorial in JBox2D website and i made it this far:

[image]

You can see i have the JBox2D trunk (i didnt quite understood what a trunk is...) I believe they are all Maven projects, and my goal is to be able to use the engine's libraries in the PhysicTest project you can see opened.

(Probabily stupidly) Im trying to import as you can see in the image and its not working, so i ask your help to solve such a simple problem that is not so simple for me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to import those projects into your project.  Go to your project properties, build path, and then click on the libraries tab.  There you can add the jbox2d libraries to your PhysicTest project.